# How to expire a webpage after certain period of time; and how does it affects in the Google's Indexation?

Tags: asp.net, e-commerce, asp.net-webpages, google-search-console, expires-header

I have a question about multi-vendor e-commerce portal.

Sellers offer particular offer for a time-being. For each offers, a new webpages are created, they are listed in site-map and crawled by Google.

My client doesn't want to show those pages once the offer is expired. So how to setup an auto-expiration of those web-pages? I am looking for the methods for asp.net technology. Can I achieve it using HTTP header, or do I need to do something with database and server query?

Once those pages are expired, then should I remove from sitemap? How does that affect in Google's indexation? Are those pages show up under 404 errors in Google Search Console? If yes, then after a few months, there will be a long list under 404 errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think so that it's a valid concern for all e-commerce store who provide such offers.

What I would recommend is to create a single page for your offer and post all your offers on that page which would redirect to that particular page and once the offer has expired then remove it from that main offer page and to some extent it would resolve your indexing issue too.

Hope so that it would help you out.

If you still have any concern please feel free to ask.

Comment: Hi.. thanks for  your reply, but it doesn't help in that way.

Comment: Could you kindly brief further what exactly is your concern?

Answer (score 0):

One of the methods to do this, is to add an expiration date for each web-page and expire those pages after that date.